# Using F# as replacement for Linux shell scripting

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, f#

After learning f# I would also like to use f# as a replacement for shell (bash,sh) scripting.
Is there anyone having experience using f# for this purpose?

Do there exist f# Linux system  libraries with functions like?:

- ismountpoint(path)
- processlist
- killprocess
- other system interface functions

Comment: What about the option of invoking PowerShell functions from your F# script?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there are no specific libraries for Linux but you can make use of System.Diagnostics as below to get processes and also to Kill (with care) :

```
let main args =
    let procs = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()
    for proc in procs do
        printfn "%i: %s" proc.Id proc.ProcessName
        proc.Kill() |> ignore
    0
```

Comment: Some system api  functions exist in both Linux and Windows, so these will work.
For the missing part I will have to write wrappers with the .net Process.Start() around Linux system commands (executable programs like mountpoint).
Best would be to write a .net library in C on Linux system api libraries, but this is quite complex.